# Volume of a hemisphere

Tags: integration

I think I'm confusing myself ...
I've seen a bunch of ways to derive the volume of the hemisphere by integrating over height like this:
[image]

but I was trying to do it by integrating over theta from 0 to pi/2 where theta is the angle from the vertical. So letting $ r = R \sin \theta $, I thought that I could simulate stacking disks of varying radia as $ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi R^2 \sin^2 \theta R d\theta$, where $R d\theta$ is the thickness of said disk, but I appear to be missing a sine and I have no idea where it could possibly come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing sine comes from $|\,dh\,| = |\,d(R\cos\theta)\,| = R\sin\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: gah! I know XD I just figured it out too %\ ... ugh, this was bugging me for like an hour ..... It makes sense, the height part has to be perpendicular to the disk.

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own. Would appreciate if you accepted my answer nonetheless.

Comment: I got to it a super ghetto way too %\ ... said that the vertical component of $R d\theta$ is $ R d \theta \cos (90 -\theta) $ ... your way is so much easier XD so embarrassing = -___- = i think that's probably a sign it's time to put down the pencil for today ...